# Automatically resizing Fancybox with an iframe for content

Tags: javascript, iframe, fancybox

I have an iframe being loaded by Fancybox. Inside the iframe, I'm loading jQuery so that I can `$('html').height();` to get the proper height of the actual content within the iframe.

- In FF, this seems to allow me to resize the iframe (and FancyBox) appropriately
- In chrome, this value is reported approximately 5px to 20px short of the actual height of the content.
- In IE 8, the value that is reported is the initial height of the fancybox window that is opened, even on subsequent refreshes (of the iframe).

Is there a better way of getting the height of the iframe content, so that I can resize the fancybox shell so the user doesn't see scrollbars?

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.3 of FancyBox has a resize method you can use to fit the iFrame to its contents:

```
$.fancybox.resize();
```

If recollection serves, this has the side-affect of reloading the iFrame contents.
If you find that's the case, try using the height of the body tag to inform the fancybox resize, instead.

```
var height = $('body').height();
$('#fancybox-inner, #fancybox-wrap').height(height);
```

Comment: `$.fancybox.resize()` does, as you suggest, reload the iFrame contents. `$('body').height()` does not take in to account the fact that the iframe has set the height, which causes the `body` to keep that height.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for

```
$(document).height()
```

I tried using $('html').height() and I got strange values.

Comment: `$(document).height()` at least for me, returns the same values that `$('html').height()` does, so this isn't going to work either :(